# как конвентировать текст в цифровой код?

Tags: c++

Есть ли стандартная библиотека или готовое решение, которая может конвертировать символы например как делает этот сайт.
https://allcalc.ru/node/67

Можно без русского языка

Comment: в `QT` `QByteArray`, наприме. Вообще, задача элементарнейшая, можно чистым си написать функцию

Comment: Непонятно, в какой кодировке данный сайт выдает кириллические символы (а == 149425292825)?

Comment: @asianirish, пробел превращается в 142725.

Comment: @Qwertiy А что там за принцип кодировки?...

Comment: @Harry, посмотрите в дебаггере код javascript. Они используют `escape()`. Пробел превращается в `%20`. Потом для каждого получившегося символа `charCodeAt - 23` зачем-то.

Comment: @Harry, я не смотрел)

Comment: @Harry, посмотрел: `function str_to_num(form) {
num_out = "";
if(form.input.value == "") alert(e);
else {
str_in = escape(form.input.value);
for(i = 0; i < str_in.length; i++) {
num_out += str_in.charCodeAt(i) - 23;
}form.output.value = num_out;
form.input.value = "";
   }
}`, ну и [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape).

Comment: @Qwertiy Мда, как по мне - несколько, гм... бредово.

Comment: @Harry, кажется, я понял, зачем escape. Так от многозначных кодов избавляются - у него же нет фиксированной ширины поля. Хотя и так я не уверен, что это кодирование однозначное.

Comment: @Harry, вот обратное преобразование, но я его пока не понял: `function num_to_str(form) {
str_out = "";
if(form.output.value == "") alert(e)
else {
num_out = form.output.value;  
for(i = 0; i < num_out.length; i += 2) {
num_in = parseInt(num_out.substr(i,[2])) + 23;
num_in = unescape('%' + num_in.toString(16));
str_out += num_in;
}
form.input.value = unescape(str_out);
form.output.value = "";
   }
}`

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, это уже из серии "О, месье понимает толк в извращениях!" (с) Анекдот. Не могу придумать практической ценности...

Comment: @Harry, длина всегда 2, потому что 123 и дальше будут экранироваться, меньше 33 - тоже, а он вычитает 23. Упихался в 2 цифры.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, но экранировка капитально раздувает сам код... Какой-то он неэстетичный :)

Comment: @Harry, ну в принципе utf8 примерно так же устроен. Хотя можно было тут его и применить, наверное.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102259/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-harry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может не мудрить и сделать вот так:

```
for (char ch : s)
  printf("%03o", (unsigned char)ch);
```

Comment: А почему не `"%02X"`? :)

Comment: @Harry, потому что просили цифры. Впрочем, можно было делать `%03d` - что-то я перемудрил. Первая мысль была как раз про `%02X`.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, Вам надо конвертировать строку в oct, ну или в hex или bin

Но по сути Вам Нужен OCT

Вот пример как это можно сделать :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>


int main() {
    std::string msg{"Test message"};

    std::stringstream ss;

    for (const auto& val : msg) {
        ss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(val);
    }
    auto hex_str{ss.str()};
    ss.str("");
    std::cout << "HEX string : " << hex_str << std::endl;

    for (const auto& val : msg) {
        ss << std::oct << static_cast<int>(val);
    }
    auto oct_str{ss.str()};
    ss.str("");
    std::cout << "OCT string : " << oct_str << std::endl;

    for (const auto& val : msg) {
        ss << std::bitset<8>(static_cast<long long unsigned int>(val));
    }
    auto bin_str{ss.str()};
    ss.str("");
    std::cout << "Bin string : " << bin_str << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```